# Conditionally determine the required-ness of a field

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to refer to a sub-schema of certain property (**Kind** in the example) from a different property in the schema, and then enforce some more conditions on it. Important thing to note is I cannot make those changes where I've defined **Kind**, I need to refer to it from some other property and then add conditionals on top of it.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "Kind": {
      "$id": "#/properties/Kind",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "Foo",
        "Bar"
      ]
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "$ref": "#/properties/Kind",
        "const": "Foo"
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "MyField"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

A json object like below should fail the validation, because **MyField** property is absent

```
{
  "Kind": "Foo"
}
```

I don't want the following solution, since this is just a simplified version and ultimately I want to refer to **Kind** value from another property. If I do following, then `#/properties/Kind` is interpreted relative to where I refer **Kind** so it doesn't refer to the **Kind** at the top level. I want a solution which uses the $ref and $id keywords.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "Kind": {
      "$id": "#/properties/Kind",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "Foo",
        "Bar"
      ]
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
       "properties": {"Kind":{
         "const":"Foo"
       }}
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "MyField"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To summarize, let's say I've following JSON structure. The last **allOf** statement is what I need to add.

```
- Kind ( enum of One,Two)
- Other
  - MyField
  - ConditionField
  - allOf ( which enforces the required-ness of MyField based on ConditionField)
  - allOf ( MyField should be not-required if Kind is One) 
[ To add this last conditional, I need to reference the value of Kind. 
I'm hoping providing $id to Kind and referring to it with $ref should be my approach, 
which doesn't seem to be working]
```

> To summarize even further, I would get my answer if we're able to get the first snippet work using $id and $ref.

Comment: I don't understand your constraint, "refer to this from somewhere else". What is "this"? The schema as a whole? The "Kind" property? The `if`? Could you provide an example of referring to this from somewhere else that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers, made some edits, let me know if you've any more concerns

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some misunderstandings that are making it difficult to fully understand the problem here, but one part of the edited question makes enough sense that I think I can start things off and we can iterate on the answer as necessary.

Let's start with some of the things that don't make sense in hopes that it helps clarify possible misunderstandings.

`$ref` can't change the behavior of a schema. If you can't do something without `$ref`, then you can't make the schema behave another way by introducing `$ref`. The only exception to that rule is recursive schemas, which would require an infinitely large and repeating schema without using `$ref`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to get from `$id`, but it's pretty safe to say you don't need it for this. In any case, the `$id` used the question is invalid. An anchor can not have a `/` in it. Even if it was valid, it would be redundant because you can reference that location with the same JSON Pointer without an anchor.

> MyField should be not-required if Kind is One

I'm not sure if "not-required" means forbidden or optional. Everything is optional by default in JSON Schema, so if you meant optional, there is nothing to do here. Therefore, I'll assume for now that you mean forbidden. Here's what that would look like.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Kind": { "enum": ["One", "Two"] },
    "Other": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "MyField": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "Kind": { "const": "One" }
        },
        "required": ["Kind"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "Other": {
            "not": { "required": ["MyField"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```